# Javascript ASP>NET get siblings/neighbours

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview and i have text boxes and uneditable text  fields in each row.
For the textbox that I have ...I have an onblur function...
I generate these textboxes from the server as follows

```
 "<input type=text name=\"txtPrice\" id=\"txtPrice_{0}\" value=\"{1}\" maxlength=\"10  \"  runat=\"server\" class=\"g1 g2\" style=\"width:71px;\"  onblur=\"javascript:myfun(this);\" />");
```

For each text box that I have in the row I want to get its neigbouring labels/txtboxes by using javascript
Remeber I cannot pass values rather I want to pass the textbox object just like I am doing in the above code

IMPORTANT:I dont know weather the label will be its direct neighbour...i want to get the neighbour using the coulmn name/header text

Or if I can pass the complete row to Javascript from the server side??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use JQuery, you can do something like this:

```
    function myFun(obj){
        var label = $(obj).parent().children('label').first();
    }
```

This link helped me and could help you too: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/